# Guess the number game ( Client - Server)

Tags: python-3.x

Server:

```
import socket
import random


randnumber = random.randrange(1,20)
ip = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5000
n = 1
tries = 0

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((ip,port))
s.listen(5)
print("...<<")

while True :
        (c,a) = s.accept() 
        print("Sundedemenos me ton ",a)     
        data = c.recv(1024).decode()    
        if (data):
            wellcome = ("Welcome to the guess the number game!")
            c.send(wellcome.encode())
            gues =("What is your guess? ")
            c.send(gues.encode())
            value = int(c.recv(1024).decode())
            print (value)
            goal = abs(value-randnumber)
            print(goal)

c.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1",5000))


hello = ("hello")
s.send(hello.encode())

wellcome = s.recv(1024).decode()
print (wellcome)

gues = s.recv(1024).decode()
print (gues)

while (gues):

    if not gues:
        break
    else:

        value = input()
        s.send(value.encode())



s.close()
```

Hello,
why the client is running 1000000000000000 times why the break is not working?.
i just want to make the game run on the server and the client for example "wellcome to the game" > "whats your guess?" > "5" > "your are close" > "6" > "you are the winer"> THE END

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an always true loop because `gues` is never changing!

```
while (gues):

if not gues:
    break
else:

    value = input()
    s.send(value.encode())
```

Also, I think both `while` loops are in the wrong places:

- In the client, the while loop never reads from the socket, so how does it get the server's answer?
- In the server I think you need a second while loop. The first tells the server "while you have another client", then you show the welcome message and then you have "while the client is guessing/hasn't found the answer"

Hope it helps, unfortunately don't have the time to implement it but I think it is a good exercise you should do :)